# The Normal Vector of two 3D vector's Cross Product

Tags: cross-product

I am wondering why the cross product of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ would get the Normal Vector of the plane generated by them? I know it is the definition, but I am still wondering why we can get it just by calculating their cross product.

Is there any proof?

---

This is cross product of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ :

$$(a,b,c) \times (d,e,f) = (bf-ce, cd-af, ae-bd)$$

Comment: You can calculate *dot product* of $(a,b,c)\times(e,f,g)$ in each of the initial vectors and see that it must be zero. The cross product is the unique vector with this property up to a scalar coefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you believe that the scalar product of two non-zero vectors is 0 exactly when they are perpendicular, then its easy. You just have to evaluate:

$\mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c})$

for either
$\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{b}$ or  $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{c}$. You can do this using the coordinate expansions you mentioned above or using algebraic properties such as the triplet product expansion of the cross product/scalar product together with the anti-commutativity of the cross product $\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} = - \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{a}$ (and here setting $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{b}$, this must then be the $\mathbf{0}$ vector).